# В WebStorm пропало автодополние

Tags: webstorm

Если ввести например название объекта и поставить точку - то всё ок, открывается меню автодополнения. Но если просто начать вводить имя функции, которая есть в этом файле, то ничего не происходит. Если полностью ввести имя функции, экспортируемой из другого файла и нажать ctr + пробел, то она автоматически не появится в импорте.

То есть хочу написать debugger
Ввожу deb. Раньше дописывалось автоматически debugger. ctr + пробел не помогает.

Или хочу использовать ранее объявленную в файле функцию searchStatus()
Ввожу searchSt. Раньше бы дописался остаток или появилась бы подсказка на ctr + пробел. Сейчас ничего =(

Может после обновления какие-то настройки пропали? Webstorm 2017.3.5

Comment: попробуйте инвалидировать кэши (*File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*). и проверьте, не включен ли *File | Power Save Mode*

Comment: Возможно что-то по плагинам отвалилось.

Comment: @gil9red почти все вопросы не про написание кода (хотя иногда и про написание тоже) на Stack Overflow можно направить к соответствующим техподдержкам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, сломались индексы. Пожалуйста, попробуйте инвалидировать кэши (**File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**). Еще стоит проверить, не включен ли **File | Power Save Mode**